# Splitting string with comma, issue with money

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like below which i'd like to split by comma's. But there's an issue with the money which is also has comma in it.
What i like to achieve; if there's a number after comma do not seperate from that one. I'd like to do the job with javascript.

> 025056-03110,245056030,1,Standart Discount,Standart Discount,*15,940.00USD*,29/11/2017,1,

What i've tried so far with thousand combinations;

> [^\,!\?]+

What i expect as a result;

```
025056-03110
245056030
1
Standart Discount
Standart Discount
*15,940.00USD*
29/11/2017
1
```

Comment: This is a non-sense situation. A better question to ask yourself is why the source of this data doesn't use a separator that doesn't appear in the separated values. This data format as it is, is broken. Instead of working around with dirty hacks, it would be better to fix the problem at its source.

Comment: Your expected result is not consistent with your specification. For example, the first comma is followed by a number, yet you still split the string there.

Comment: Disagreed with all you three ^

Comment: Everyone here have a -1 ((

Answer (score 1):

The solution here is to use `.match()` with **[this regex `/(\d+,\d{3}[.]\d+\w+)|(\d+[\-][\d\w]+)|([\/\d\s\w]+)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/ZDJzVe/1)**, it will split all the elements and skip the numbers that have a comma.

This is how should be your code:

```
var str = "025056-03110,245056030,1,Standart Discount,Standart Discount,15,940.00USD,29/11/2017,1";
var matches = str.match(/(\d+,\d{3}[.]\d+\w+)|(\d+[\-][\d\w]+)|([\/\d\s\w]+)/g);
```

**Demo:**

```js
var str = "025056-03110,245056030,1,Standart Discount,Standart Discount,15,940.00USD,29/11/2017,1";
var matches = str.match(/(\d+,\d{3}[.]\d+\w+)|(\d+[\-][\d\w]+)|([\/\d\s\w]+)/g);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: [
  "025056-03110",
  "245056030",
  "1",
  "Standart Discount",
  "Standart Discount",
  "15",
  "940.00USD",
  "29/11/2017",
  "1"
]

Comment: @Piterden I edited the solution and it works perfectly.

Comment: If not negative, then positive)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = '025056-03110,245056030,1,Standart Discount,Standart Discount,15,940.00USD,29/11/2017,1,';
let price = str.match(/[A-Za-z],(\d+,?\d{1,3}\.\d{2}\w{3})/)[1];
let temp = price.replace(',', '|');

console.log(
  str.replace(price, temp)
    .split(',')
    .map(v => v.replace('|', ','))
    .filter(v => v)
);
```

Comment: Breaks when you change to `940.00USD`

Comment: So you need to think first, then vote it down, my friend, @charlietfl

Comment: Why is that? if a solution isn't extendible then it doesn't work. Also I am not a down voter. I simply pointed out a bug. And how would OP use 2 regex?

Comment: @charlietfl check it out, my friend

Comment: @chsdk See the result of my snippet

Comment: @Piterden Nice approach as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do it like this:

[`(?:\d+,(?=\d+\.).+?(?=,)|[\w-\/.\s]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/2axIPE/1)

```js
var pattern = /(?:\d+,(?=\d+\.).+?(?=,)|[\w-\/.\s]+)/g;
var str = "025056-03110,245056030,1,Standart Discount,Standart Discount,15,940.00USD,29/11/2017,1,";
var matches = str.match(pattern);
for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    if (matches[i].indexOf('USD') !== -1) {
        matches[i] = "*" + matches[i] + "*";
    }
}
console.log(matches.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather [`match`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) with alternatives: [`\*[^*]*\*|[^\s,][^,]*`](https://regex101.com/r/tIfzS4/5)

```js
var s = '025056-03110,245056030,1,Standart Discount,Standart Discount,*15,940.00USD*,29/11/2017,1,';
var res = s.match(/\*[^*]*\*|[^\s,][^,]*/g);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy Asterisks not visible in your non-code sample, escape those with backslash.